# Echo specified array content

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I have a JSON file which iam using ( file_get_contents ) from a url, to extract the values to a good formatted way. The problem is that i need to echo out a specific value content but failed to do that. So here is the piece of code iam providing here may be if someone would like to help me out to do it.

```
Array
(
    [type] => result
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => My Radio Name
                    [song] => Artist Name - Song Name
                    [track] => Array
                        (
                            [artist] => Artist Name
                            [title] => Song Name
                            [album] => Unknown
                            [royaltytrackid] => 0
                            [id] => 542
                            [playlist] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 45
                                    [title] => ALL SONGS
                                )
                               .....
```

SO i need to echo out [artist] AND [title] Which will be echoed as:
Artist Name | Song Name

Thanks in advance any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: i try this but without luck:
echo $array[0]["array"][0]["artist"];

Answer (score 1):

Depends on format of your json but below code should work:

```
foreach ( $json['data'] as $entry ){

    foreach ( $entry['track'] as $track ){

       echo $track['artist'] ." | ".  $track['title'] ."<br/>";

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok the code you gave its working but its echoing the complete name like this:  Artist Name - Song Name. I need to separate just to read the artist name itself and title itself.

Comment: change my answer as there is a nested loop, check now. You should still adjust it to your exact JSON format,it only shows you the general approach

Comment: When iam replacing the one you said ( song ) and i put ( artist ) its returning null page.

Comment: The above code is only echo:

|
|
|
And so on. I try to remove the second part after the dot.( ." | ".  $entry['title'] ."<br/>" ) then its again giving empty page.

Comment: my bad, check now

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'artist'